# strtotime returning the same date on a Sunday

Tags: php, date

So I have 5 variables that I use to store last weeks dates using the php function strtotime()

The only problem is, every Sunday the dates return the same dates. Like today for instance, using $monday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday last week'));
will return me a date of 2019-04-08

Obviously being the 2019-04-21 today that should be 2019-04-08.
The problem starts here though, if I use this $tuesday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('tuesday last week')); it will return me a date of 2019-04-08 and the date today is 2019-04-21 so it should return return me the date 2019-04-09.

The same is true if I try any of the weekdays. They all return me the same date, 2019-04-08.

What's more is its also true if you are using date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday this week'));

works for monday but returns monday for all of the days of the week when on a Sunday.

I saw someone say use a function, so I was researching on here and tried it but it returned the same result.

```
//// function I tried but it proved to produce the same results.///////
function lastfriday() {
        return date('Y-m-d', date('N')==5 ? strtotime('today') : strtotime('last friday'));
    }






////////// this is the code I have been using but as I explained, every Sunday it gets buggy
echo $monday = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'monday last week' ) );
echo $tuesday = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'tuesday last week' ) );
echo $wednesday = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'wednesday last week' ) );
echo $thursday = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'thursday last week' ) );
echo $friday = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'friday last week' ) );
echo $saturday = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'saturday last week' ) );

running that code on today 2019-04-21 produces the results

2019-04-08
2019-04-08
2019-04-08
2019-04-08
2019-04-08
2019-04-08
```

Comment: its showing the correct date from 08 to 13

Comment: Very interesting!. For me it shows 2019-04-15..2019-04-21 (Mon..Sun). And that looks wrong, because it is this week. I tested different `setlocale()`, but the result remains the same.

Comment: Very interesting indeed. On my computer, your code works just fine.

Comment: Could this be possibly due to a php.ini file config issue? This is a hosted server running a cpanel. Ill create a local test environment and some more testing.

The server in question is running php 5.6.40